# Issue in wrapper class

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, wrapper-class, search

[image]

In the following snapshot we are fetching parent and child records using wrapper class.Selected child records should be displayed in selected course.But whenever i select child records only last record is selected in the selected course section.

This is my class:

```
    Coursesearch= Database.query(soql1);
    WrapperList = New List<WrapperClassEx>();
    for(University__c acc: Coursesearch){
        WrapperList1 = New List<WrapperClassEx1>();
        for(Course_Detail__c Det:acc.Course_Detail__r)
        {
            WrapperList1.add(New WrapperClassEx1(det));
        }
        WrapperList.add(New WrapperClassEx(acc,WrapperList1)); 
    }                    
}

public PageReference getselected() {
    selectedcoursesearch2.clear();
    for(WrapperClassEx1 wrapAccountObj : WrapperList1)
    {
        if(wrapAccountObj.selected == true)
            selectedcoursesearch2.add(wrapAccountObj.acc1);
    }
    return null;
}

public list<Course_Detail__c> getSelectedcoursesearch() {
    if(selectedcoursesearch2.size()>0)
    {
        system.debug('//////////////////////////////////'+selectedcoursesearch2.size());
        return selectedcoursesearch2;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and page:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!coursesearch1.size!=0}">
                    <table id="tableAccount" class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="headerRow">
                                <th class="actionColumn">Action</th>
                                <th>Account Name</th>
                                <th>Industry</th>
                                <th>Billing Country</th>
                                <th>Createdby</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <apex:repeat id="repeatAccount"
                            value="{!coursesearch1}"
                            var="item">
                            <apex:variable var="acc" value="{!item.acc}" />   
                            <tr id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:account" class="dataRow">
                                <td class="actionColumn">
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectAccountRow"
                                        value="{!item.Selected}"
                                        onclick="javascript:toggleSelectAll(this, '{!$Component.repeatAccount}');"/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="dataCell">
                                    <apex:outputLink id="linkShowHide" value="javascript:toggleContactRow('{!$Component.repeatAccount}')">
                                        <img id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Img" src="/s.gif" class="showContacts" border="0" height="11px" width="11px" style="padding-right: 4px;"/>
                                        <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
                                    </apex:outputLink>
                                </td>
                                <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.name}" /></td>
                                <!--<td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.billingcountry}" /></td>
                                <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.CreatedById}" /></td>-->
                            </tr>

                            <tr id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Contact" class="dataRow" style="display:none;">
                                <td colspan="100" style="padding:10px; padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <h3>Contacts</h3>
                                    <br/>                                        
                                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">                                            
                                        <table id="tableAccountContacts" class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr class="headerRow">
                                                    <th class="actionColumn">Action</th>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Email</th>
                                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <apex:repeat id="repeatAccountContacts"
                                                value="{!item.cd}"
                                                var="subitem">
                                                <apex:variable value="{!subitem.acc1}" var="con" />
                                                <tr class="dataRow">
                                                    <td class="actionColumn"><apex:inputCheckbox id="selectContactRow" styleclass="ContactCheckbox" value="{!subitem.Selected}">
                                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getselected}" reRender="Selected_PBS" /></apex:inputCheckbox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputtext value="{!con.Name}" /></td>
                                                    <!--<td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!con.email}"/></td>
                                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!con.phone}" /></td> -->                                              
                                                </tr>
                                            </apex:repeat>
                                            </tbody>

                     </table>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Can you also post your page code (only relevant part, the sidebar is not needed)

Comment: please provide the page code as well. The above code does not explain your record selection logic on the page.